# Sphinx - how to call command? (windows)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to get up and going with Sphinx on a windows box.  I have no prior Sphinx experience and have done little with python as well.

I've installed sphinx per pip, but can't for the life of me figure out how to use it!

I'm following the First Steps with Sphinx from their site: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.8/tutorial.html and am stuck on

> Just run `$ sphinx-quickstart`"

Please don't laugh, but... how (where) do I run this?  The command prompt doesn't recognize it, I can't find an install location to run it explicitly (or any evidence of it on my windows box other than the pip install console output), if I try from within python I get

> NameError: name 'Sphinx' is not defined`

A little push in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sphinx-quickstart` executable is in the **[python_install_dir]/Scripts**.
[python_install_dir] probably equals something like **c:/Python27** or **c:/python3x**.

You can call the command with its full path ([python_install_dir]/Scripts/sphinx-quickstart) or add the Script directory in your PATH environment variable to call it using only the executable name.

Comment: Got it, thanks... my python install directory was in my appdata folder.